# Why is my Hashtag python script converter not working?

Tags: python, camelcasing

I am working on this script that will take a string and convert it into a camel case hashtag. The problem I am running into is that every time I run my code, it runs indefinitely and I'm not entirely sure why.

```
if s == "": # a constraint given by the problem
    return False
elif len(s) > 140: # a constraint given by the problem 
    return False
else:
    i = 0
    while i < len(s)+1:
        if s[i] == " ": # if there is a space the next character would be a letter, logically
            if s[i+1] != " ": # if the next character is a letter (not a space) it will capitalize it 
                s[i+1].upper()
    i += 1
    return "#" + s.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: can you please add expected input and output test case

Answer (score 2):

Even if you properly indent `i += 1` as some answers suggest, this was never going to work. What do you think this does:

```
s[i+1].upper()
```

Strings in Python are immutable -- you can't change them.  This returns `s[i+1]` as an uppercase letter, but it doesn't change `s`.  I.e. it's a no-op!

Let's see if we can make your code work with a minimum of changes:

```
def hash_camel(s):
    if s == "": # a constraint given by the problem
        return False

    if len(s) > 140: # a constraint given by the problem
        return False

    string = "#"
    i = 0

    while i < len(s):
        if s[i] == ' ':  # if there is a space, the next character could be a letter
            if s[i + 1].isalpha():  # if the next character is a letter, capitalize it
                string += s[i + 1].upper()

                i += 1  # don't process s[i + 1] again in the next iteration

        else:
            string += s[i]

        i += 1

    return string

if __name__ == "__main__":

    strings = [
        '',
        'goat',
        'june bug',
        'larry curly moe',
        'never   odd   or     even',

    ]

    for string in strings:
        print(hash_camel(string))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test2.py
False
#goat
#juneBug
#larryCurlyMoe
#neverOddOrEven
>
```

If I were writing this from scratch, I might go about it this way:

```
def hash_camel(s):
    if s == "" or len(s) > 140:  # constraints given by the problem
        return None  # it's data, not a predicate, return None

    words = s.split()

    return '#' + words[0] + ''.join(map(str.capitalize, words[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I came up with for you:

```
def cam(s):

    if s and len(s) <= 140:
        s = s.title().replace(s[0],s[0].lower()).replace(' ','',1)
        return "#"+s
    return False

print(cam('Camel case words are fun.'))
```

Output:

```
#camelCaseWordsAreFun.
```

Comment: This doesn't output what the OP describes.  I suggest you look up 'camel case' then go back and reread the question.

Comment: Nice use of `str.title()`!  However, as your own example shows, this code is buggy.  The `replace()` call is doing as much harm as good.  For example: `"Fast and furious"` -> #fastAndfurious and `"fast and furious"` -> #FastAndFurious -- neither outputs the desired camel case result `"#fastAndFurious"`

Comment: Thank, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You run into an infinite loop because `i += 1` is placed outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
if s == "": # a constraint given by the problem
    return False
elif len(s) > 140: # a constraint given by the problem 
    return False
else:
    i = 0
    while i < len(s)+1:
        if s[i] == " ": # if there is a space the next character would be a letter, logically
            if s[i+1] != " ": # if the next character is a letter (not a space) it will capitalize it 
                s[i+1].upper()
        i += 1
    return "#" + s.replace(" ", "")
```